# Append streamed data to file on Minio on the fly

Tags: go, streaming, minio

I have some data streamed into my go service.

What I need to do is to stream these data and append it to a file in minio, without having to download the file.

I try my best to avoid having to wait until all the data are streamed to me then upload it to Minio, i rather do it on the fly if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The MinIO `PutObject` takes an `io.Reader` interface as its 4th parameter (see https://docs.min.io/docs/golang-client-api-reference.html#PutObject).  You can use a `*File` as returned by `os.Open()` since `*File` implements the `Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)` method of io.Reader.

But you can use any type that implements the `io.Reader` interface.  You could create your own type or maybe use a `*bytes.Buffer`.